comparing row count from file to CSV control file
Inside a Azure synapse pipeline, I need to find and compare the row count of the CSV file with summary file stored in Azure Blob storage.
If the comparison fails then pipeline will stop, if the counts match then can proceed ahead in the pipeline.
pipeline, which components

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

If your rows are less than 5000, you can use lookup activities for this requirement which will give the required row count of the files.
Create datasets for your files and give those to two lookup activities like below. Make sure you uncheck the First row only option in both activities.

Now, take an if activity and use the below expression to compare both row counts.
@equals(activity('count of control').output.count,activity('count of csv').output.count)


If the condition satisfies, you can add the further activities in the True activities of if activity. Otherwise, you can stop the pipeline by not giving any activity in the False activities of if activity.
If the row count in your control file is like below sample.
filename,count
one.csv,5

Then, compare the count property from the control file lookup activity output array with the CSV file row count.
And, if the CSV file count is more than 5000, you can use ADF dataflow for this.
Get the row count of CSV file using below transformations in the Dataflow.

Source (csvfile)
DerivedColumn  -> create new column rowcount and give some value.
Aggregate - count(rowcount)
sink - Use sink cache to pass this row count value to the pipeline.

After dataflow activity, compare the row count of the CSV file with your control file count using if activity.

Given my CSV is more than 10 Mill rows and in Synapse, I also found an alternative, what if I use Notebook, df_count = (df.count() == df_CNTL_zipped.iloc[1][0])... spits out "True". How do I get it to show True so I can place in the expression: activity('notebook_row_check').output.    (true or something)

Yes, you can use synapse notebook for this. Return the counts from the notebook and call that notebook from pipeline. Then use if condition to compare those.

Check this to exit the notebook

@DanWang, Is your issue resolved?

issue resolved. Many thx
